# Cast a UITabBar inside a UITabBarController to my own class

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, subclass, uitabbar

I am using a UITabBarController, and I would like to cast/change the tabBar property to my own tabBar subclass.  I CAN do this in Interface Builder by just selecting the TabBar and changing the class to my own, this works fine.  But for this implementation, I am not using Interface Builder.

So, how can I do the same thing since I am building the TabBarController programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

subtabbar:UItabbar

```
subclass then  

declare in viewcontroller also (import them to .h)

subtabbar *subtab;

retain and synthesize it

in viewdidload

self.tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

self.subtab=[[UITabBar alloc]init];

self.tabBarController.tabBar=(UITabBar*)self.subtab;
```